# How do I add bootstrap cdn to wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I used following code to add Botstrap using cdn but it doesn't word in wordpress. I tried to add directly in header and it works perfectly but I want to do this through wordpress functions

```
function my_scripts_enqueue() {
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap-js', '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), NULL, true );
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap-css', '://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, NULL, 'all' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_enqueue' );
```

Also I tried this and it didn't work either:

```
function enqueue_my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.1', true); // we need the jquery library for Bootstrap js to function
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), true); // all the bootstrap JavaScript goodness
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts');
function enqueue_my_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_styles');
```

Comment: https ://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494517/how-to-add-bootstrap-cdn-to-my-wordpress

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Bootstrap CDN to my Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494517/how-to-add-bootstrap-cdn-to-my-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Friend try with this code :

```html
function rpthem_enqueue_style(){
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrapcss','https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', false, null );
}
function rpthem_enqueue_script() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstapjs', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js', false, null );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rpthem_enqueue_style' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'rpthem_enqueue_script' );
```

Answer (score -1):

You just Edit your Header.php and paste this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It works but this is not the Wordpress standard way of doing this